# How to plot a Cramer’s V heatmap for categorical features?

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, bokeh, heatmap, categorical-data

The association between categorical variables should be computed using Crammer's V. Therefore, I found the following [code](https://www.kaggle.com/phaethonprime/eda-and-logistic-regression) to plot it, but I don't know why he plotted it for "contribution", which is a numeric variable?

```
def cramers_corrected_stat(confusion_matrix):
    """ calculate Cramers V statistic for categorical-categorical association.
        uses correction from Bergsma and Wicher, 
        Journal of the Korean Statistical Society 42 (2013): 323-328
    """
    chi2 = ss.chi2_contingency(confusion_matrix)[0]
    n = confusion_matrix.sum().sum()
    phi2 = chi2/n
    r,k = confusion_matrix.shape
    phi2corr = max(0, phi2 - ((k-1)*(r-1))/(n-1))    
    rcorr = r - ((r-1)**2)/(n-1)
    kcorr = k - ((k-1)**2)/(n-1)
    return np.sqrt(phi2corr / min( (kcorr-1), (rcorr-1)))


cols = ["Party", "Vote", "contrib"]
corrM = np.zeros((len(cols),len(cols)))
# there's probably a nice pandas way to do this
for col1, col2 in itertools.combinations(cols, 2):
    idx1, idx2 = cols.index(col1), cols.index(col2)
    corrM[idx1, idx2] = cramers_corrected_stat(pd.crosstab(df[col1], df[col2]))
    corrM[idx2, idx1] = corrM[idx1, idx2]

corr = pd.DataFrame(corrM, index=cols, columns=cols)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 6))
ax = sns.heatmap(corr, annot=True, ax=ax); ax.set_title("Cramer V Correlation between Variables");
```

I also found [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/gallery/heatmap_chart.html). However, I am not sure if it uses Crammer's V to plot the heatmap or not?

Really, I have two categorical features: the first one has 2 categories and the second one has 37 categories. Could you please let me know how to plot Crammer's V heatmap?

Some part of my dataset is [here](http://www.kaggle.com/shebrahimi/financial-distress).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bokeh is a direct plotting library, not a statistical plotting tool. Generally speaking, it does not perform any statistical computations on your behalf. Bokeh could certainly display a heatmap constructed in this way, but you would need to construct the coordinates, color mapping, etc. yourself.

Comment: check out http://shakedzy.xyz/dython/nominal.html for a nice way to visualize relationships between both categorical and continuous variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the problem? The code is absolutely right.

`ax` in this case ia a correlation matrix beetwen variables.
Using "contribution" is not correct but you can see in [the article](https://www.kaggle.com/phaethonprime/eda-and-logistic-regression) bellow 
Quote

*

> "This isn't right to do on the Contribution variable, but we'll do
>   more with a model later."

*
The author shows this variable for example only.
In your case what's the reason to make plot Crammer's V? You have just two variables (as I see) and you will get only one correlation coefficient Crammer's V

But of course you can repeat the code on your data and get plot Crammer's V heatmap

Comment: Thanks. If I use just train data to compute Cramer's v, it would be zero. However, if total data is applied, it would be 0.13.  I know the first approach is true, but the reality is that if "x121" will be converted into 37 dummy variables and included in the lasso (l1) logistic regression, some of these newly created dummy features would have non-zero coefficients. I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know how to interpret these results? @Edward

Comment: With respect to the aforementioned results, is it right to do so? Or, more insight would be gained if the association between each of these dummy features and target variable will be investigated?

It should be mentioned that all these 37 dummy variables are included in total dataset but when it splits into train and test sets, some of these dummy variables appear just in the train set or test set.

Comment: @ebrahimi I guess the difference 0.13  & zero depends on size of your dataset & number of levels of the variables. Define dummy variables which show zero by Crammer and unite them into one level (for examle "etc"). You can do it with mapping by dict. And retry